# Split table data based on time gaps

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, window-functions

Let's say we have a time-series dataset of entities metadata imported into postgres table `Stats`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS POSTGIS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Stats";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Stats"
(
    "time" BIGINT,
    "id" BIGINT,
    "position" GEOGRAPHY(PointZ, 4326)
);
```

And here is the samples of table:

```
SELECT 
    "id",
    "time"
FROM
    "Stats"
ORDER BY 
    "id", "time" ASC

id|time|
--+----+
 1|   3|
 1|   4|
 1|   6|
 1|   7|
 2|   2|
 2|   6|
 3|  14|
 4|   2|
 4|   9|
 4|  10|
 4|  11|
 5|  32|
 6|  15|
 7|  16|
```

The business requirement is to assign route-id to entities in this table, so when the time for each entity jump over `1 second` it means the new flight or route for that entity. the final result would like this for previous samples:

```
id|time|route_id|
--+----+--------+
 1|   3|       1|
 1|   4|       1|
 1|   6|       2|
 1|   7|       2|
 2|   2|       1|
 2|   6|       2|
 3|  14|       1|
 4|   2|       1|
 4|   9|       2|
 4|  10|       2|
 4|  11|       2|
 5|  32|       1|
 6|  15|       1|
 7|  16|       1|
```

And this would be the new summary table of the routes:

```
id|start_time|end_time|route_id|
--+----------+--------+--------+
 1|         3|       4|       1|
 1|         6|       7|       2|
 2|         2|       2|       1|
 2|         6|       6|       2|
 3|        14|      14|       1|
 4|         2|       2|       1|
 4|         9|      11|       2|
 5|        32|      32|       1|
 6|        15|      15|       1|
 7|        16|      16|       1|
```

So how this complex query should be constructed?

Comment: If I understood correctly, for ID `4` on time `10`, routeID must be `2`. Why 3 was provided?

Comment: @Arun. yeah that's correct, it only has two routes with ID 1, 2

Comment: Gaps and islands. Solved times before on here.

Comment: @shawnt00. Actually this is a historical aircraft flights dataset imported from https://opensky-network.org/datasets/states/ which should be modeled with routes!

Comment: The specifics of the data don't change the nature of the query. Look up gaps and islands and you'll discover hundreds of variations on the same theme.

Comment: @IMAN4K, Which part you need help, to assign `routeID` or to create `new summary` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by "time") rn from Stats
)
select id,
    min("time") as start_time, max("time") as end_time,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by "time" - rn) as route_id
from data
group by id, "time" - rn
order by id, "time" - rn
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=c272bc57786487b0b664648139530ae4

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have table `stats` in hand, the following query will create a table by assigning `route_id`:

**Query to assign route_id using `recursive-cte`:**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_route AS 
with recursive cte AS 
(
  SELECT id,  prev_time, time, rn, rn AS ref_rn, rn AS route_id 
  FROM 
  (    
    SELECT 
      *,
      lag(time) OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY time) AS prev_time,
      row_number() OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY time) AS rn 
    FROM stats
  ) AS rnt
  WHERE rn=1

  UNION

  SELECT rnt2.id, rnt2.prev_time, rnt2.time, rnt2.rn, cte.rn AS ref_rn,
    CASE 
      WHEN abs(rnt2.time-rnt2.prev_time)<=1 THEN cte.route_id
      ELSE cte.route_id+1
    END AS route_id
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN
  (
   SELECT 
     *,
     lag(time) OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY time) AS prev_time,
     row_number() OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY time) AS rn 
   FROM stats
  ) AS rnt2
   ON cte.id=rnt2.id AND cte.rn+1 = rnt2.rn
)

SELECT id, time, route_id FROM cte;
```

**Query to check if route_id assigned was correct:**

```
select id, time, route_id 
from tbl_route 
order by id, time
```

**Query to create `new summary` table:**

```
select id, min(time) as start_time, max(time) as end_time, route_id
from tbl_route
group by id, route_id
order by id, route_id, start_time, end_time
```

**Recursive-CTE Query breakdown:**

Since recursive cte has been used, the query may look messy. However, I tried to break it down as follows:

1. There are 2 main queries getting appended using `UNION`, First one will assign `route_id` for start of each id, Second will do it for rest of the rows for each id
2. `rnt` and `rnt2` has been created because we need `ROW_NUMBER` and `LAG` values to achieve this
3. We joined cte and rnt2 `recursively` to assign `route_id` by checking the difference in the time

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c60ffcdd57ee65dfd173e5bfb75eae4c)